# concatMap vs mergeMap with store Selector

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have spent many time learning difference between **mergeMap** and **concatMap** to clearly understand the differnce, and it' is clear to me now. I used good resources like https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com and https://www.learnrxjs.io with other websites.

Both of this operators keeps the incoming source and subscribe to all emited values with difference in ordering. But in my project i have met a situation when using **mergeMap** and **concatMap** differs a lot to me, and i want to understand why.

Here is a code sample:

```js
const Stream$ = from(requiredDocs.documents_type)
          .pipe(
            mergeMap(docID => this._store.select(selectDocumentTypeByID(docID))),
            scan((acc: Array<DocumentType | undefined>, curr) => {
              console.log('curr - ', curr)
              acc.push(curr)
              return acc
            }, [])
          ).subscribe(val => console.log(val))
```

*Explanation*: i am generating source from array **requiredDocs.documents_type**, then using values emitted to select from a store using selector - **selectDocumentTypeByID(id: number)**. The latter is a simple Array.find function that either returns undefined or a found object. Then i use **scan** rxjs operator to generate resulting Array of values from selector

**Expected result:** [ {obj}, {obj}, {obj} ] - three objects that are returned by select observable

```
mergeMap - result is as expected - [ {obj}, {obj}, {obj} ]

concatMap - result is just one obj(*first one*) - [ {obj} ]
```

If i change store selector to simple **of(docID)** rxjs operator it works as expected.

Why concatMap only returns one obj when using with store selector ?

Comment: To reduce lines of code, you can use `toArray` operator instead of `scan`

Comment: sorry, but i just tried replacing toArray vs scan and in my case its not working - just empty resulting value in .subscribe()

Comment: Could that be cuz of source is not completed ? But it's only a from([1,2,3]) operator. Shouldn't it complete by itself when passed in array ends ?

Comment: need to end store selectors to toArray() work properly

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-x9yxvq?file=index.ts

Comment: i added example, intervals are like selectors

Answer (score 1):

Yes, magic of question asking works except that for this time with lots of pain and thinking :) Answer is in concatMap definition. This operator subscribes to each outer source Observable and **only subscribes to following when previous has been completed**

Funny, how question came up in my head suddenly and kinda randomly :) After many hours of thinking about it. So, in order for my example to work properly i need to complete store.selector. Which i yet don't know how to do, but to me the difference between these two operatos is now clear which is a major thing.

mergeMap in its turn does not wait for source Observable to finish and this is why it works as i needed. Cheers all :)

Comment: To finish you can use `first()` operator, `this._store.select(selectDocumentTypeByID(docID).pipe(first()) `

Comment: @shutsman Little typo in your answer. pipe operator should be used on .select() not on selector Memoized function